# prevent users from adding text with white spaces to listBox?

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, whitespace

I want to prevent users from adding white spaces to a listbox (no spaces)

Code i've written already:

```
if (serverTextBox.Text == " ")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Do Not Enter WhiteSpaces", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: `serverTextBox` is a `ListBox`?

Comment: Why are you trying to prevent them instead of handling it (trimming for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx), for example with this concise LINQ query:

```
if(serverTextBox.Text.Any(Char.IsWhiteSpace))
    MessageBox.Show("Do Not Enter WhiteSpaces", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
else
    yourListBox.Items.Add(serverTextBox.Text);
```

Presuming that `serverTextBox` is a `TextBox` which text you want to add to the `ListBox`.